# How to change default typography for Textfields and such via theme in Material UI v5?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Is there a way to map the default typography for TextField and all my inputs via theme? I know I can do this

```
components: {
    MuiInput: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                fontSize: '16px',
                lineHeight: '25px'
            }
        }
    },
```

but I wish to find a way to map it to 'body2'

```
MuiInput: {
    defaultProps: {
        typographyProps???: {
            variant: 'body2'
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want all your `input`s to have a `font-size` equal to `body2`?

Comment: @HamedSiaban exact

Answer (score 2):

For using `body2` font size value in another component, You need to access the `theme` object's `typography` property.
Then You will set the MUI TextFiled's `font-size` equal to that value from the `theme` object.

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createTheme({});
theme!.components!.MuiTextField = {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
        fontSize: theme.typography.body2.fontSize, // this is the default mui body2 font-size
        lineHeight: "25px", // and any other styles you want...
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And You can change the body2 fontSize when defining the theme object:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    body2: {
      fontSize: 80,
    },
});
theme!.components!.MuiTextField = {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
        fontSize: theme.typography.body2.fontSize, // this will be 80px
        lineHeight: "25px", // and any other styles you want...
      },
    },
  },
};
```

EDIT:
If You are not ok with overriding the `theme` after defining it, You can use this approach:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";
const myBody2FontSize = 20px;
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    body2: {
      fontSize: myBody2FontSize,
    },
  }, 
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
            fontSize: myBody2FontSize , // this is the default mui body2 font-size
            lineHeight: "25px", // and any other styles you want...
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: yeah I know I can do this, but I have to override the theme after createTheme. Which I find kinda weird, but if thats my only option I will do this

Comment: I added another approach, may be that helps. I don't think that there would be another way to achieve what You want without overriding theme object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it via classname. It's a bit awkward because an input doesn't actually use `Typography` internally.

```
MuiInput: {
    defaultProps: {
        className: 'MuiTypography-body2'
    }
}
```

Or possibly

```
MuiTextField: {
    defaultProps: {
        InputProps: {className: 'MuiTypography-body2' }
    }
}
```

Comment: neither works sadly :/